# What method does Rails use to get the parameter name for an ActiveRecord resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've dug up and down the ActiveRecord and FormHelper documentation and API, and I can't find how Rails goes from an AR class like `class Namespace::MyResource < ActiveRecord::Base` to the parameter name `namespace_my_resource`.

While I'm sure it's not hard to write my own method to do so `class ActiveRecord::Base; def to_pname; self.class.name.underscore.gsub(/\//, '_'); end; end`, this seems un DRY.

Answer (score 1):

```
include ActiveSupport::Inflector
tableize "Namespace::MyResource"
```

=> "namespace/my_resources"

That get's you close.  Add a simple gsub to change the slashes to underscores:

```
tableize("Namespace::MyResource").gsub(/\//,'_')
```

=> "namespace_my_resources"

Not sure if this is exactly how ActiveRecord does it, but solves it in a pretty general way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the singular version for `params[:namespace_my_resource]`

```
"Namespace::MyResource".underscore.gsub(/\//,'_')

=> "namespace_my_resource"
```